# Using Regex to validate the number of words in a text area

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am attempting to write a MVC model validation that verifies that there is 10 or more words in a string.  The string is being populated correctly, so I did not include the HTML.  I have done a fair bit of research, and it seems that something along the lines of what I have tries should work, but, for whatever reason, mine always seem to fail.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

(using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, in a mvc 4 vb.net environment)

Have tried `([\w]+){10,}`, `((\\S+)\s?){10,}`, `[\b]{20,}`, `[\w+\w?]{10,}`, `(\b(\w+?)\b){10,}`, `([\w]+?\s){10}`, `([\w]+?\s){9}[\w]`, `([\S]+\s){9}[\S]`, `([a-zA-Z0-9,.'":;$-]+\s+){10,}` and several more varaiations on the same basic idea.

```
<Required(ErrorMessage:="The Description of Operations field is required"), RegularExpression("([\w]+){20,}", ErrorMessage:="ERROZ")>
Public Property DescOfOperations As String = String.Empty
```

Correct Solution was `([\S]+\s+){9}[\S\s]+`

Comment: Can you describe the text strings that you are trying to match?  Is there punctuation or any special characters that the regex should be aware of?

Comment: Not really.  Basically, looking for a sentence or two, so there will be punctuation, but I am not expecting anything other than ',.:$  and at present, I am not inclucing those in the tests I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT Moved accepted version to the top, removing unused versions.** Unless I am wrong and the whole sequence needs to match, then something like (also accounting for double spaces):

```
([\S]+\s+){9}[\S\s]+
```

Or:

```
([\w]+?\s+){9}[\w]+
```

Comment: Unfortuantly, neither of those work.  As far as I can tell, and from what I have read, they should(although, perhaps replacing the w with an S, in the case of punctuation) work, but, for whatever reason, they don't.

Comment: Updated mine a couple times there as I made some mistakes - always good to check the reference :) Try what is there now.

Comment: Sadly, still not.  They simply report ERRORZ on any list of words.  Also, shouldn't the {10} be {10,}, as I want at least 10 words?  And, in vb.net, do I need \\ or \?

Comment: Based on your criteria you are asking for 10 or more words, but don't care about how many more? In that case you want to stop matching to not take anymore performance hit than required.

Comment: One more pair of regex to try.

Comment: All right, I think there is some progress. However, if there is a double space in the first ten words, using the first new suggestion, there is a failure. Fixed by making it `([\S]+\s+){9}[\S\s]+`. Thank you.  Should I mark this as the answer now, or let you edit it a bir first?

Comment: Edited to account for double spaces.

Comment: And... Marked as answer.  You might want to move the correct one to the top though

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

`([a-zA-Z0-9,.'":;$-]+\s){10,}`

Comment: Accepts anything with a length of at least 10 characters.  Are you thinking that the vb regular expression does not have \w or \s?

Comment: <Edited my regex for the proper whitespace count>  I am not familiar with the VB implementation of regex, but traditionally `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which will not match all English-language punctuation, which it sounds like is needed here.

Comment: I was figuring that a \S, which is any non-white space character, would cover that.  Sadly, that edited regex seems to return false on all strings(tried "01234456788 ", "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven")

Comment: Edited my answer again, this seems to work better.  Yes, `\S` will work most of the time, but it is generally better to be as specific as possible with your regex, if you know exactly what characters you are expecting.

Comment: It still fails on the same two cases, sadly.  Interestingly enough, it is almost as though the greedy `+` is failing to be greedy, as making it \s? has it validating 112233445.

Comment: That is strange.  Using `(\w+\s?){10,}` would be equivalent to `(\w+){10,}`, since the shitespace is now optional and `\w+` is greedy. Perhaps there is some strange way that VB reads regex that I am just unaware of.  What happens if you try `(([a-zA-Z0-9,.'":;$-])+(\s)){10,}`

Comment: It does not seem to validate `112233445`, `1122334455`, or `one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven`  I am honestly not sure what is going wrong with this(hence the question)